# magento: how much is paid & Shipping method

Tags: php, magento, orders

(first post on stackoverflow!)

I'm trying to figure out how I can see how much is already paid.

```
    $order_paid = $order->getGrandTotal(); <- i know that this is wrong
    $order_total = $order->getGrandTotal();
```

This is for (afterpay) function where the order has a "order_total" price but the "order_paid" field is 0.00,

I know I can do this in my module by asking which payment method an order is set.
To do this simple, I want Magento to give me the "order_paid" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with:

```
$order_paid = $order->getTotalPaid();
```

Comment: How i missed that i dont know. It works, thank you my friend!